# Copy Failed with the Dockerfile provided in Google knative code-sample

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

newbie to GCP here. Wondering has anyone also facing the error:

```
Step 3/10 : COPY go.* ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

when using the Dockerfile provided in Google Cloud knative GitHub page [here](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/main/code-samples/eventing/helloworld/helloworld-go/Dockerfile)?
The helloworld-go file was copying the code provided [there](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/main/code-samples/eventing/helloworld/helloworld-go/helloworld.go).
The command I was using was as below:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[my_google_cloud_projct_id]/helloworld
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference the current/working directory (`.`):

```sh
gcloud build submit ${PWD} --tag=gcr...
```

Conventionally, `${PWD}` is replaced with `.` which is easily overlooked.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. I added **`.`** to the command got this error `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) The required property [project] is not currently set.`. I used `gcloud config set project [MY_PROJECT_ID]` but then got the same error as the original post.

Comment: That's progress  I assume you've not used `gcloud config` to set a default project (good!). You can add `--project=...` to the end (keep everything else) of the `gcloud build submit` command and replace `...` with the Google Project where your want to run the build.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, no luck, the same error.. This was the command I used - `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[MY_PROJECT_ID]/helloworld --project=[MY_PROJECT_ID]`.